# Does using the `describing:` argument within a `description` property recursively call the description property?

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, linked-list, computed-properties

I'm working through a book right now and they've extended a class that implements nodes for a linked list. The extension makes the class conform to the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol. However, within the `description` computed property, they've specified that an instance should be converted in part by using the `String(describing: )` initializer. That is, inside of the `description` they have `String(describing)`. Does this mean that there is some sort of recursion occurring?

Here is the example code from the book:

```
public class Node<Value> {
  public var value: Value
  public var next: Node?

    public init(value: Value, next: Node? = nil) { 
        self.value = value
        self.next = next 
    }
}


extension Node: CustomStringConvertible {
  public var description: String {
    guard let next = next else {
      return "\(value)"
    }
return "\(value) -> " + String(describing: next) + " " }
}
```

I know that the `describing` initializer causes the body of `description` to be executed. Does the execution of `description` cause another node to be converted to a `String`?

Comment: Yes, it is a recursive implementation, but it doesn't "convert a node to a string", it just creates a string that represents that node

Comment: Your question asks "Does using the `describing:` argument within a `description` property recursively call the description property?" but in the body, you say "I know that the describing initializer causes the body of description to be executed.". Haven't you answered your own question?